# join temptable using joinsin sql

Tags: sql-server, join, temp-tables

I have two columns vendornum and invoice status in my temp-table. Now I want to join three more columns EY_AmountIncl_LC,EY_AmountExcl_LC,EY_datedocumented to that temptable and output should look like following.

```
VendorNumber EY_AmountIncl EY_AmountExcl EY_datedocumented  InvoiceStatus
50000471     281072          281072         00:00.0           V-Parked Items 
5200991      80000            80000         00:00.0           V-Parked Items
5200595     72401.6          72401.6         00:00.0           V-Parked Items
5202384    402207.68        402207.68        00:00.0           V-Parked Items
```

Is there may way to do it.I am very new to sql .can any one help me in this.I am using management studio 2014

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Please give table definition from where you are fetching columns `VendorNumber` `EY_AmountIncl` `EY_AmountExcl` `EY_datedocumented` `InvoiceStatus`

Comment: Where are these other columns coming from? Help us help you - please share the tables' structures and some sample data.

Comment: I have an another table with details of vendor as vendordata from where i want to take these three columns and join it to temptable .I even derived temptable from vendordata table