# join one temptable with another table with different columns and difference in no of columns in both tables in mysql server

Tags: sql-server, join

I have two tables. one table `#temptable` with columns `vendornumber` and `invoice status`, and the other `vendordata` table with `EY_AmountIncl_LC`, `EY_AmountExcl_LC`, `EY_datedocumented`.

How do i join two tables to get the output as one table with all 5 columns in table. Can any one help?I have the code for temptable

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp_table3') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #temp_table3


select VendorNumber,stuff( (select distinct ','+dbo.vendordata.InvoiceStatus
                               from dbo.vendordata
                               where dbo.vendordata.VendorNumber = dbo.vendordata.VendorNumber 
                               for xml path('')
                              ), 1, 1, ''
                            ) as InvoiceStatus
    into #temp_table3
    from dbo.vendordata
    group by VendorNumber
```

Now to this temp table i want to add three more columns `sum(EY_AmountIncl_LC)AmountIncl_LC ,SUm(EY_AmountExcl_LC)AmountExcl_LC,max(EY_datedocumented) Datedocumented` group by vendor num.can any one help

Comment: Please add some sample data to your question.  It will be hard for anyone to help you just based on a two sentence description, with no data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [join temptable using joinsin sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52270352/join-temptable-using-joinsin-sql)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CROSS JOIN` like:

```
SELECT * FROM #temptable CROSS JOIN vendornumber
```

You can also apply comma (`,`) between two table name

```
SELECT * FROM #temptable, vendornumber
```

Above example will display all five columns

Comment: vendornumber is one of the columns in #temptable when i used the above second  code i ended up with error saying An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.